# If there was an object such as a bucket travelling through the atmosphere very fast could the air caught in it transition to a liquid?

Tags: pressure, astrophysics, drag, viscosity

The question came to me after thinking of the pressure waves in front of a spacecraft during re-entry.

Would the pressure caused by the air being compressed cause the air to liquefy and if so at what speed?(Assume the object is a standard cylindrical bucket)

Or would the air resistance cause the air that is in the bucket to heat up and stay in it's liquid state?

What would happen if the air was replaced steam instead ?

Answer (score 0):

The air in the bucket would obviously heat up as the bucket traveled at high speed through the atmosphere.  Because of this, the air in the bucket would definitely be above the critical temperature of all of the components in the air, making it impossible to condense.